# LinkedLists of LinkedLists with recursion

Tags: java, linked-list, tree

I have a data structure made of linkedlists of linkdelist.

For example:

```
[ [A,B,C] [D,E,F] [A,B] [E,F] ]
```

My goal is to find those linkedlists that are never contained in the whole structure. For istance, [A,B,C] and [D,E,F] are never contained by others, because they contain respectively [A,B] and [E,F].
I need to use recursion since I'm dealing with a tree, so when I find a linkedlist with these feature I have to recall my function.

That's my implementation:

```
private void treeGen(Node<LinkedList<String>> parent, LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> partitions) {

    for (int i=0; i<partitions.size();i++) {
        for(int j=0; i<partitions.size();i++)
        {   
            //the condition discussed so far
            if(!partitions.get(i).containsAll(partitions.get(j)) && parent.getData().containsAll(partitions.get(j)))
            {
                //create node
                Node<LinkedList<String>> child = new Node<LinkedList<String>>();
                //set value
                child.setData(partitions.get(i));
                //child of parent node
                parent.addChild(child);
                //new parent node, recursion
                treeGen(child, partitions);
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

Despite I compare all the possible combinations, I miss some nodes in the tree.
Is there something wrong related to the linkedlists?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "contain" here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess that nested for is supposed to increment j rather than i. I suggest you to avoid naming indexes like that, it can result in a really confusing code and, at times, in this kind of errors.